# Previous widgets are not displayed after installing a new module

Tags: node-red

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
     "dashboard-evi": "~1.0.2",
     "node-red-contrib-ui-led": "~0.4.11" 
 }
```

There are no errors in the console, I used the palette manager for installation, I restarted it after installation.

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean here, which node did you install after which the things disappeared? [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77215597/edit) the question to make it clear what the exact steps were. Also `dashboard-evi` is not the Official dashboard instance, you should probably be using `node-red-dashboard`

Comment: @hardillb, indeed, by installing `node-red-dashboard` the error is gone